# how to calls Stored procedures from WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 7.1.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-micro-integrator

Good afternoon, I was reading the WSO2 documentation to know if it is possible to call stored procedures and at this moment I just saw that is if possible. I use WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 7.1.0; The documentation where found this:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Sample+364%3A+Using+Mediators+to+Execute+Database+Stored+Procedures
The problem is that this documentation is for WSO2 ESB 6.x.x but I am using WSO2 7.1.0  and i've been searching documentation about stores procedures on the wso2 official website but unfortunately, i couln't find anything :(
For logic, I suppose that if is possible calls store procedures from the 6.x.x version should possible do this in 7.1.0 version.
Does anyone believe can be do this of stores procedures for call it from WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 7.1.0 such as in WSO2 ESB 6.x.x???
Or does anyone know how do it?? thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, most of the documentation that is created for ESB/EI is applicable to Micro Integrator(EI 7.1) as well. [Here](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/develop/creating-artifacts/data-services/creating-data-services/) is the documentation on how to create a Dataservice, once you create the dataservice instead of a simple query you can call the stored procedure referring to the sample you shared. [This](https://www.yenlo.com/blogs/oracle-stored-functions-and-wso2-dss/) may also come in handy. [This](http://mycodeideas.blogspot.com/2017/03/wso2-dss-calling-stored-procedures-with.html) too.

Comment: thanks for help me, finally i can do the stored procedure call correctly, only one have that do a stored procedure in a db and put the call sql statment in the Integration Studio flow like another SQL sentence for generate his results, thanks.